# Yeoman Yo WebApp Generator Issue

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I am trying to generate a WebApp using Yeoman `Yo` Command but I keep getting following error:

```
pdclap-2stjvs1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$ yo webapp

Error: Cannot find module './lib/env'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/index.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
pdclap-2stjvs1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$
```

Is it an environment variable issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a npm issue. Maybe it didn't copy all files or didn't install a dependency.

Install the latest version of both npm and yo, and retry.